# Blank page with google maps and Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Googlemaps displays a white page in Ionic 3 on browser and mobile. I have installed the plugin correctly and imported everything. When testing it prompts me to allow location then displays a white page without even a Google logo.

I have tried reinstalling all plugins and checking the API key, all seems valid.

.html

```
<ion-content padding>
    <div #map id="map"></div>
  </ion-content>
```

.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FindridePage } from './findride';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FindridePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(FindridePage),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ]  ,
  exports: [
    FindridePage
  ]
})
export class FindridePageModule {}
```

.ts

```
import { NavController,IonicPage,Platform  } from 'ionic-angular';
import { GoogleMap,GoogleMaps } from '@ionic-native/google-maps';
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

declare var google: any;

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-findride',
  templateUrl: 'findride.html'
})
export class FindridePage {
@ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
map: any;
markers = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private _googleMaps: GoogleMaps,public platform: Platform,private geolocation: Geolocation) {

      setTimeout(this.initMap(), 10000);

  }



  initMap() {
    console.log('starting');
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({ maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true }).then((resp) => {
      let mylocation = new google.maps.LatLng(resp.coords.latitude,resp.coords.longitude);
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, {
        zoom: 15,
        center: mylocation
      });
    });
    let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
    watch.subscribe((data) => {
      this.deleteMarkers();
      let updatelocation = new google.maps.LatLng(data.coords.latitude,data.coords.longitude);
      let image = 'assets/imgs/blue-bike.png';
      this.addMarker(updatelocation,image);
      this.setMapOnAll(this.map);
    });
  }
  addMarker(location, image) {
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: this.map,
      icon: image
    });
    this.markers.push(marker);
  }

  setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++) {
      this.markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
  }

  clearMarkers() {
    this.setMapOnAll(null);
  }

  deleteMarkers() {
    this.clearMarkers();
    this.markers = [];
  }
 listride(){
    this.navCtrl.push('ListridePage');
 }


}
```

Comment: do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @Olian04 Only warnings about cordova. "cordova not detected"

Comment: Then i suggest you scale down. Create a new app with just the essentials to get the map working. If it then works, you know that its something on your end messing it up. If it doesn't work then i suggest you read up on the library again, or post an issue on their issue tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set height and width of the map element as below and you will see the map. if it is loaded.

```
<div #map id="map" style="height:500px; width:300px;">
```