# Google maps integration with ionic resulting in blank screen with no errors

Tags: typescript, maps, ionic4, angular8

I'm trying to add google maps to my web application but without fail I manage to just get a blank screen and to make maters worse no errors! Here is my code so far. I feel like it may be somethign to do with the mapElement but my typescript knowledge is too poor and nothing i've found online seems to work

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-google-maps',
  templateUrl: './google-maps.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./google-maps.component.scss'],
})
export class GoogleMapsComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('map', { static: false }) mapElement: ElementRef;

  text: string;
  map: any;
  constructor() {
    this.text = "hello World"
  }

  initMap() {
    let coords = new google.maps.LatLng(45, 100);
    let mapOptions: google.maps.MapOptions = {
      center: coords,
      zoom: 20,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
  }


  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.initMap();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }



}
```

Then trying to use the component in events.html

```js
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color = "primary">
    <ion-title>Events</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
<app-google-maps></app-google-maps>
</ion-content>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you set height?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this URL:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/57405762/5251807

Seems you have not set height and width of div container.